# Submitting form to PHP with dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form which is empty in HTML file and I'm adding input elements to it using javascript but when I submit the form to PHP file (Controller.php) it doesn't send anything

**HTML File**

```
<form id="test" action="Controller.php" method="POST">
    <!-- QUESTIONS WILL APPEAR HERE-->
    <div id="questions"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Finish">
</form>
```

**JS File**

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('questions');
        d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
            "<div class='question'>"
            + "<h4 id='questionTitle'>Question Title goes here...</h4>"
            + '<ul>'
            + '<li id="ans1"><input type="radio" id="1st-option" name="selector">'
            + '<label for= "1st-option" >Answer 1</label>'
            + '<div class="check"></div>'
            + '</li>'


            + '<li id="ans1"><input type="radio" id="2nd-option" name="selector">'
            + '<label for= "2nd-option" >Answer 2</label>'
            + '<div class="check"></div>'
            + '</li>'


            + '<li id="ans1"><input type="radio" id="3rd-option" name="selector">'
            + '<label for= "3rd-option" >Answer 3</label>'
            + '<div class="check"></div>'
            + '</li>'


            + '<li id="ans1"><input type="radio" id="4th-option" name="selector">'
            + '<label for= "4th-option" >Answer 4</label>'
            + '<div class="check"></div>'
            + '</li>'
            + '</ul>');
```

**PHP File**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

The result of $_POST is an empty array `Array ( )`, I have tried to add elements to the form statically (in HTML) and it worked, but I can't do it from JS,IDK why this happens

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. When I use your exact code I get a result of `Array ( [selector] => on ) `. I only get `Array ( ) ` when I don't select any of the radio buttons but that's expected..

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Yes, it was one of the silly mistakes I have done, it won't work if I didn't select any radio, as you suggest. Also, I had an issue with file names. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs have no value attribute :

Change :

`<input type="radio" id="1st-option" name="selector">`

to

`<input type="radio" id="1st-option" name="selector" value="your_value">`

For the **"Answer 1"** the value could be **"answer1"** for exemple, or **"1st-option"** like the id that you've set, or anything you want. But you must have something in it. Else it will be empty.

Comment: Not the solution to the problem. The default `POST` value for a `radio` is `on` - Works with IE/FF/Chrome (not tested on Opera but I would have thought the same)

Comment: @Alex Vand It wasn't what I'm looking for but it really helped to avoid future problems